# Can we create procedure at current database similar as from another database in same server? looking for shorthand method

Tags: mysql

> Suppose when we want to create the same table with data from other database at same server then we can achieved by below query.

```
  create table table_name as select * from database_name.table_name;
```

> same way, we want to create the procedure. is it possible:)

```
  I'm looking for any short way for create the procedure.
```

Comment: That could be dangerous imagine if the procedure contained fully qualified  table names or called another function or procedure which initiated an update to another db. If I was you I would look very carefully at any code migrated from 1 db to another and just cut and paste.

Comment: Yup, you are right but sometimes we need to do quickly work so I'm thinking for a shortcut way. :)   Actually, my scenario have to write the same procedure in the different database. :)

Comment: You could write some code to extract the procedure from information schema. Routines

Comment: It's a good idea :) Thanks for this suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

For purpose of transferring data from one DB to another mysqldump utility is more suitable than stored procedure especially in case of gigabytes of data.
You can dump even specific table

```
mysqldump -u... -p... your_db your_table > your_dump.sql
```

Then dump data to another db

```
mysql -u... -p... your_second_db < your_dump.sql
```

If you want some of automation, the easiest way may be simple script - just put these two commands - and schedule running tasks periodically